# ReflectionException in laravel: it cannot find a request that i just created

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Request file named UsersRequest (in App\Http\Requests)
and at the top

```
use App\Http\Requests\UsersRequest
```

I get this error: "ReflectionException in RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php line 57:
Class App\Http\Requests\UsersRequest does not exist"
..although i manually created the file with `php artisan make:request UsersRequest`

Yesterday i renamed UserRequest to UsersRequest.
I use PhpStorm and this editor finds UserRequest, but not UsersRequest (this last one is in yellow)

Is there any way of refreshing the project or to tell laravel that the UsersRequest really exists ?

Comment: do a `php composer dump-autoload`

Comment: php composer dump-autoload doesn't work.it works  composer dump-autoload but nothing happens, i get the same error

Comment: try `php artisan optimize`

Answer (score 0):

I went back to UserRequest and it works fine. Maybe is something related to pluralism or the request name has to match somehow the class name